# Find the volume of the solid under the surface $z =\sqrt{x^2 - 2xy + y^2}$ over a given region

Tags: integration

> Find the volume of the solid under the surface $z = \sqrt{x^2 - 2xy + y^2}$ over the region $R = \{(x,y), 0 \leq x\leq  1 , 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$ .

How do you ascertain the boundary region and set the limits for integration?
I can't visualise this.

Comment: Use the graph of the surface to find the boundary region.

Comment: 1. The volume under this surface is unlimited and has infinite volume. Are you asking for the volume enclosed by this **and by $z=0$**? 2. Sure that $$\sqrt{x^2-2xy+y^2}$$ cannot be simplified somewhat?

Comment: Did you notice that $x^2- 2xy+ y^2= (x- y)^2$ so that $\sqrt{x^2- 2xy+ y^2}= |x- y|$?  You are **told** that the boundary is the rectangle with left side x= 0, right side x= 1, bottom side y= 0, top side y= 1.  So you need to integrate $\int_0^1\int_0^1 |x- y| dydx$.  The only "tricky" part is dealing with that absolute value.  For x> y, |x- y|= x- y so you can write that part of the integral as $\int_0^1\int_0^x x- y dydx$.  For y> x, |x- y|= y- x so you can write that part of the integral as $\int_0^1\int_x^1 y- x dydx$.

Comment: @Did  The statement says "over the region $R$" (probably in the plane $z=0$.)

Comment: @RobertZ True, but the OP would obviously benefit from figuring out what their own problem is about, the region of integration included.

Comment: @Did I see. I hope that, after reading these comments, OP will be able to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that $\sqrt{x^2 - 2xy + y^2}=\sqrt{(x-y)^2}=|x-y|$. Split the region $R=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ into two parts: $R_1$ where $|x-y|=x-y$ and $R_2$  where $|x-y|=y-x$. Then
\begin{align}
V&=\iint_{R}|x-y|dxdy=\iint_{R_1}(x-y)dxdy+\iint_{R_2}(y-x)dxdy\\&=\int_{x=0}^1\left(\int_{y=0}^x(x-y)dy\right)dx+\int_{x=0}^1\left(\int_{y=x}^1(y-x)dy\right)dx.
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so, but why do we need a modulus for this?
Also, is there a diagram/graph I can see to visualise this?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$. Moreover take a look here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqrt(x%5E2-2xy%2By%5E2)

Comment: ok, why do we split the parts into 2 parts? why not just integrate from 0 to 1 instead of your proposed 0 to x, and x to 1

Comment: Are you able to integrate $\iint_{R}|x-y|dxdy$ without splitting?

Comment: i'm not sure haha i would have done it wrongly i suppose

Comment: What have you found? Note that here $\iint_{R_1}=\iint_{R_2}$.

Comment: i would get to nowhere sir

Comment: @Rah I edited my answer. Try again!

Comment: Thanks! this is much clearer and i chanced upon this video to help me explain too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWcwhA2BwVk

Comment: Let me know. BTW in the video the integral is evaluated by splitting...

Comment: got the ans, it's 1/3 ! phew. hell of a integration. thanks all!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.